# Draw icons according to Id

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two classes: `Item` and `CardMore`, here they are respectively:

```
data class Item(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val icon: Int,
val color: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)

data class CardMore(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val icon: Int,
val type: IntArray)
```

And there is a `listOf` of these classes to display in Card() in Jetpack Compose:

```
val itemList = listOf(
    Item(0, "Recycling", R.drawable.recycle_icon, recycle_icon_color),
    Item(1, "Paper", R.drawable.leaf_icon, leaf_icon_color),
    Item(2, "Glass", R.drawable.beer_bottle_icon, beer_icon_color),
    Item(3, "Metal", R.drawable.metal_icon, metal_icon_color),
    Item(4, "Plastic", R.drawable.plastic_icon, plastic_icon_color),
    Item(5, "Dang.  waste", R.drawable.toxic_icon, toxic_icon_color),
    Item(6, "Electronics", R.drawable.electronics_icon, electronics_icon_color),
    Item(7, "Not recycling", R.drawable.close_icon, close_icon_color)
)

 val cardItems = listOf(
    CardMore(8, "Waste paper", R.drawable.paper, intArrayOf(0, 1)),
    CardMore(9, "Bottles", R.drawable.bottles, intArrayOf(0, 2, 4)),
    CardMore(10, "Vials", R.drawable.vials, intArrayOf(2, 4, 7)),
    CardMore(11, "Metal can", R.drawable.metal_jar, intArrayOf(0, 3)),
    CardMore(12, "Cloth", R.drawable.cloth, intArrayOf(0)),
    CardMore(13, "Glass", R.drawable.glass, intArrayOf(0, 2)),
    CardMore(14, "Medicine", R.drawable.medicine, intArrayOf(0, 5)),
    CardMore(15, "Furnitures", R.drawable.electro, intArrayOf(0, 6)),
    CardMore(16, "Appliances", R.drawable.furn, intArrayOf(0, 1)),
    CardMore(17, "Food waste", R.drawable.food_waste, intArrayOf(0)),
    CardMore(18, "Batteries", R.drawable.battery, intArrayOf(0, 5, 6)),
)
```

`cardItems` is used to draw the information that is in Card() with the subtext "More Details" in the screenshot. `ItemList`, in order to display information on Card(), you need the text "More Details".

I want to make it so that the cards that are under the text display icons that are higher than the text by category. That is, let's say "Waste paper" is a category of "Recycling." and "Paper", and I need to display exactly these icons (some sort of sorting). For "Bottle" - "Recycling.", "Glass" and "Plastic". I think it's clear from the screenshot what I want.

I thought it was possible to work with arrays somehow. For example, "Waste Paper" in the `listOf` `cardItems` has an array with values 0 and 1 { `intArrayOf(0, 1)` }, where "0 and 1" are the id in the `listOf` `ItemList`. If the id value is in the array, then we draw icons with these IDs.

I have such code:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End) {
                    cardItems[0].type.forEach { typeId ->
                        val item = itemList.find { it.id == typeId }
                        if (item != null && typeId in cardItems[0].type) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                                contentDescription = item.name,
                                tint = item.color,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(25.dp)
                                    .padding(4.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
```

[image: Screenshot example]

But it turns out as in the screenshot, which is incorrect. I hope I explained it clearly.

**EDIT:** I fix it myself. Here is the the code:

```
LazyRow(modifier = Modifier) {
items(cardItems) { item ->
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
            .clickable { },
        shape = roundedRectangleShape,
        elevation = 4.dp,
        backgroundColor = white
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                item.type.forEach { typeId ->
                    val item = itemList.find { it.id == typeId }
                    if (item != null) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                            contentDescription = item.name,
                            tint = item.color,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(25.dp)
                                .padding(4.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In your code, you have `cardItems[0]`, so it seems you are always accessing the first item of the list (Waste paper), because the index is hardcoded.

Comment: I am trying this instead:

`for (currentCard in cardItems) {
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End) {
            currentCard.type.forEach { typeId ->
                val item = itemList.find { it.id == typeId }`

But this just display icons over other icons

Answer (score 1):

**Question solved!**

Here is the right code:

```
LazyRow(modifier = Modifier) {
items(cardItems) { item ->
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .width(120.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
            .clickable { },
        shape = roundedRectangleShape,
        elevation = 4.dp,
        backgroundColor = white
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
            ) {
                item.type.forEach { typeId ->
                    val item = itemList.find { it.id == typeId }
                    if (item != null) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                            contentDescription = item.name,
                            tint = item.color,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(25.dp)
                                .padding(4.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```